# Direct sum of eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a problem in Chapter 4, Algebra, Michael Artin, 2nd.

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, such that $T^2=I$. Prove that for any vector $v$ in $V$, $v-Tv$ is either an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$ or the zero vector. Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of the eigenspaces $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(-1)}$. The eigenspace $V^{(\lambda)}$ is the set of eigenvectors of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I am currently having a problem proving that $V$ is the direct sum of the eigenspaces $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(-1)}$.

I find that the set of all eigenvalues $\Lambda$ of $T$ is $\Lambda = \{1, -1\}$

and $V^{(1)}$ and $V^{(-1)}$ are $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$. Also $V^{(1)} \cap V^{(-1)} = \{0\}.$

But I am stucked here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $x=[(\frac  x  2-T(\frac  x  2)]+[(\frac  x  2+T(\frac  x  2)]$. Show that the first term belongs to $V^{(-1)}$ and the second term belongs to $V^{(1)}$.

Comment: It works! Thanks. But I am still not sure I could find how to decompose $x$ as you showed.

Comment: @HenryChoi I tried to write $x$ as $(v-Tv)+w$ so $w=x+Tv-v$. I wanted $Tw=w$. From this it was easy to guess how I should choose $v$.

Comment: $v-Tv= \frac{1}{2}(x-Tx)$. Now choosing $v$ as $\frac{1}{2}x$ seems quite reasonable. I missed to represent $x$ as you did. Thank you.